# C# Unable to use System.Threading.Tasks?

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2013, using

I'm trying to make an async method but my visual studio is not allowing me to import System.Threading.Tasks. I am able to have

```
using System.Threading;
```

but when I type

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

it says:

> 'The type or namespace name 'Tasks' does not exist in the namespace System.Threading. Are you missing a directive or assembly reference?'

Is there something I need to import? Why is it letting me use threading but not threading.tasks? I am using visual studio 2013.

Comment: Why are you using Visual Studio 2013? We are in 2018...

Comment: What Framework version are you targeting?

Comment: @Kenneth k I am targeting 3.5. What version do I change it to? This is not my program originally, I received it like this and I guess they must have had it at 3.5

Comment: @yuin265 as you can read in my answer they introduced it from .NET Framework 4.0

Answer (score 1):

`System.Threading.Tasks` is available from .NET Framework 4.0.

But since you also need `async/await`, you'll have to target .NET Framework 4.5 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

Your projects needs to use .NET framework `4.5` or later.

Comment: You're linking to an Applies to section that states `, 4.5.1, 4.5, 4.0` at the end of framework supported versions. Sure you want to claim 4.5 or later only? 4.5 added `async`/`await`, but those are not necessary to use other parts of the TPL.

Comment: Made a mistake, thought it was referencing the namespace not the Task class. Edited.